# Excel convert columns to new rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that looks like this:

```
  |   A   |     B      |     C      |     D      |
  +-------+------------+------------+------------+
1 | Name  | Language 1 | Language 2 | Language 3 |
  +=======+============+============+============+
2 | John  | English    | Chinese    | Spanish    | 
3 | Wendy | Chinese    | French     | English    | 
4 | Peter | Spanish    | Chinese    | English    |
```

And I want to generate a table that has only one language column. The other two language columns should become new rows like this:

```
   |   A   |    B     | 
   +-------+----------+
 1 | Name  | Language |
   +=======+==========+
 2 | John  | English  |
 3 | John  | Chinese  |
 4 | John  | Spanish  |
 5 | Wendy | Chinese  |
 6 | Wendy | French   |
 7 | Wendy | English  |
 8 | Peter | Spanish  |
 9 | Peter | Chinese  |
10 | Peter | English  |
```

I understand this will probably will need a macro or something. If anybody point me in the right direction it would me much appreciate. I am not very familiar with VBA or the Excel object model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do the trick. It is also dynamic supports as many language columns as you want with as many languages per person.
Assumes the data is formatted as per the example:

```
Sub ShrinkTable()
    Dim maxRows As Double
    Dim maxCols As Integer
    Dim data As Variant
    maxRows = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
    maxCols = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

    data = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(maxRows, maxCols))

    Dim newSht As Worksheet
    Set newSht = Sheets.Add

    With newSht

        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Name"
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Column"

        Dim writeRow As Double
        writeRow = 2

        Dim row As Double
        row = 2
        Dim col As Integer

        Do While True

            col = 2
            Do While True
                If data(row, col) = "" Then Exit Do 'Skip Blanks

                'Name
                .Cells(writeRow, 1).Value = data(row, 1)

                'Language
                .Cells(writeRow, 2).Value = data(row, col)

                writeRow = writeRow + 1
                If col = maxCols Then Exit Do 'Exit clause
                col = col + 1
            Loop

            If row = maxRows Then Exit Do 'exit cluase
            row = row + 1
        Loop

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Never knew about the End.Row and End.Column. You just need to add `.Name = "Master"` under the `With newSht` command to fully satisfy the OP's Question.

Comment: Changed as per suggestion.

Comment: I apologize I commented on to the wrong question. New "Master" Sheet was never a request of the OP. I only thought so because you transferred the Data to a new sheet, I believe he wanted it done in place. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: That's ok. I did it in a new sheet as its easier to recheck and to be sure no data is lost. Once he has the format he wants he can copy it wherever he wants.

Comment: A new sheet is fine guys! Thanks so much for your input. I am just trying it out now. I will report back soon.

Answer (score 0):

Messy but should work:

```
For Each namething In Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = namething.Value
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = namething.Offset(0, 2)
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = namething.Value
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = namething.Offset(0, 3)
    namething.Offset(0, 2) = ""
    namething.Offset(0, 3) = ""
Next
```

Then just sort

Answer (score 0):

The following formula should work. The data in sheet2 would always reflect the data on sheet1 so you wouldn't have to re-run a macro to create a new list.

That being said, using a macro to generate it is probably a better choice as it would allow more flexability should you need to add a 4th language or something at a later date.

In Sheet2!A2

`=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&ABS(INT((ROW()+1)/3))+1)`

In Sheet2!B2

`=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&IF(ABS(INT((ROW()+1)/3)-(ROW()+1)/3)=0,"B",IF(ABS(INT((ROW()+1)/3)-(ROW()+1)/3)=(1/3),"C","D"))&ABS(INT((ROW()+1)/3))+1)`

Add the column titles in A1 and B1 then autofill the formula down the sheet.