# VBA convert rows to columns

Tags: vba, excel

I try to make convertion from TABLE1 to TABLE2

[image: TABLES]

using vba

```
code should go here, but when i paste it, i got erro that I have to much    code
```

so, i add link to TXT document [vba code](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AiWBl-dHp1isc0y9gOdQzJCBr7g)

but can't figure out how to move the YEAR data from TABLE1 B1:G1 to column B of TABLE2.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to use PowerQuery? That would make it very simple. all you have to do is to unpivot the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel convert columns to new rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775143/excel-convert-columns-to-new-rows)

Comment: i use this post as a base of my code, but can't figure out how to pass the YEAR data from TABLE1 row  to TABLE2 YEAR column.

Comment: even without PowerQuery, this is easily doable by a) automating a pivot (use the macro recorder to get you started) b) creating a sql-querytable on `ThisWorkbook` or c) just transposing the ranges if you put some effort into it.

Comment: @Martin Dreher I am compleatly new to vba. did you saw the code I used? It's jus need a bit of twick to fit my needs. Just can't figure out how start to read the first row of TABLE1 (excluding A1)

Comment: sry, corporate IT blocked me from getting there. couldnt read it. imo this shouldnt require too much code.... looking into it, let£s see with what i can come up

Comment: @Martin Dreher maybe the image get you wrong. I just placed the both sheets in one window as there was error message saying I can't use more than two links on my post. so, the idea is that i have TABLE1 in SHEET1 and in same sheet I have Active-X button with VBA code. When you run code you get the new sheet (and each time you click it generates the increading number of sheet) where you get the outcome of TABLE2. I do not need the outcome in same sheet. Also, the data is dinamic and there will be different quantities of countries and data.

Comment: The obvious solution to that is to use `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet50")` to `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add` and then create your query table on `Destination:=.Cells(1, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use the Setup as shown in your example, this worked for me:

```
Sub tt()

Dim ws As Worksheet, nws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set nws = Worksheets.Add
i = 0
c = 0

nws.Range("A1").Value = "Country"
nws.Range("B1").Value = "Year"
nws.Range("C1").Value = "Value"
nws.Range("D1").Value = "Text"
Do While ws.Cells(2 + i, 1).Value <> ""
    j = 0
    Do While ws.Cells(1, 2 + j).Value <> ""

        nws.Cells(2 + c, 1).Value = ws.Cells(2 + i, 1).Value
        nws.Cells(2 + c, 2).Value = ws.Cells(1, 2 + j).Value
        nws.Cells(2 + c, 3).Value = ws.Cells(2 + i, 2 + j).Value
        nws.Cells(2 + c, 4).Value = "YES"
        c = c + 1
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

---

For a non-VBa Solution, you can do this with the native Worksheets-Functions like such:

Assuming you have the setup like in the picture put these Formulas in A9, B9 and C9 and drag down as suited:

For A9;

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",ROUNDDOWN((ROW(1:1)-1)/COUNTA($B$2:$G$2),0)+3))
```

For B9:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$G$2,MOD((ROW(1:1)-1),COUNTA($B$2:$G$2))+1)
```

For C9:

```
=INDEX($A$3:$G$5,MATCH(E9,$A$3:$A$5,0),MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,COUNTA($B$2:$G$2))+2)
```

Comment: sorry, but the VBA is complytly not suiting and with non VBA  I get errors

Comment: Consider the possibility that the VBA code is suiting (since it is), and that you described your problem incompletely (therefore Marco is using `Sheet50` instead of `Worksheets.Add`). If you get trouble adjusting this simplest of all possible solutions to your needs, you should aquire some basic VBA knowledge first.

Comment: @Martin Dreher you right Marting as I said I have no knowledge of VBA at all. That's why I found the code suiting me of 90% ans ask here for help for that 10%. It's shame I cant post the code here, and not sure if you saw it but if there is way to tweek it  it would be enough for me. Or rpobably I am on the wrong site. Can you tel me some other site I can use to get hepl. thanks

Comment: @Vidma please see the eddited code. This should do, what you want.

Comment: Sorry, took time to understand what changes I should do. It worked perfectly. THANK YOU A LOT!

Comment: now i try to paste data to new workbook - Dim ws As Worksheet, ows As Workbook, nws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set ows = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
Set nws = Worksheets.Add

and got small problem, as the new workbook opens with two sheets instead of one ... can't figure out where i am wrong ...

Comment: @Vidma You want to create a new Workbook for every time you run the Sub, instead of a new sheet?

Comment: @Marco Getrost Yes, and now I fugered out how to do that - Dim ws As Worksheet, ows As Workbook, nws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set ows = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
Set nws = Sheets("Sheet1") - 

but run in problemmulti languages. One machine has english and "Sheet1" works fine, but another one has lithuanian and the new workbook has sheet named as "Lapas1" and I get error  .. need to find the way to have some language dependant code of Set nws = Sheets("Sheet1")

Comment: @ Vidma What you could do is instead of refering to the sheet via Set nws = Sheets("Sheet1"), you could do this:
Set nws = Sheets(1) if its in the first position. But then it will always have to be on the same position.

Answer (score 0):

K, might aswell give you some hints on how I would do this based on the information I have.

I recon there's a ton of ways to achieve this...

- by automating a `PivotTable`-Object
- by creating a `Recordset`, then looping it's records and field-names [as shown in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543005/vba-speeding-up-code/41546220#41546220)
- by looping your Table1-`Range` in the x and y direction (like you do)
- or, as described below, using a `QueryTable` with some basic `SQL`

**Using a query table:**

A query table is basically a link to some external data (a textfile, a database, another excel-doc).

Points i like about query tables:

- connects to virtually any data source
- needs to be set-up once, can be refreshed afterwards
- changes to it's content (filters, additional columns, order, calculated fields) can be made with basic [SQL-knowledge](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp), eliminating the need to overthink some VBA-logic.

For our purpose, it is largely described with two properties (there's more to it, but we keep it simple):

- The `Connection` / `ConnectionString` stores information on your linked data (filetype, location, etc). In our case, this is the exact Excel-File we're working on. Check out [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) for more info on other fiole-types.

  Here's how your `Connection` will likely look, assuming you use an `xlsm`-File:

  ```
  OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;;Password=;User ID=Admin;
  Mode=Share Deny Write;
  Data Source=I:\yourfolder\ThisFile.xlsm;
  Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES"
  ```

  To keep things simple, paste this into **one** cell and read it into a string-variable with `con = YourSheet.Cells(1,1)`. Editing it in a cell is a lot more comfortable than inside VBA.
- the `CommandText` stores information on what data to get. We use `CommandType = xlCmdSql` here, which means that our `CommandText` will be an SQL-String, closely resembling this one:

  ```
  SELECT Country, "1990" as y1, [1990] AS y_value
  FROM [Tabelle1$A2:G5]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Country, "1991" as y1, [1991] AS y_value
  FROM [Tabelle1$A2:G5]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Country, "1992" as y1, [1992] AS y_value
  FROM [Tabelle1$A2:G5]
  ....
  ```

  Again, paste this into **one** cell, adjust the Excel-ranges to your Table1-Range, and read it into a string variable with `cmd = YourSheet.Cells(1,2)`.

  Note: creating this SQL is obviously the messy part if you got 10+years. In that case, find a way to write the SQL semi-automatically, e.g. with formulas, and then concatenate them into one string.
- This gets us started. We now can create a `QueryTable` with the aforementioned properties. The final sub looks something like

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Sub CreateQT()

      With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet50")

  chkQT:
          If .QueryTables.Count > 0 Then .QueryTables(.QueryTables.Count).Delete: GoTo chkQT

          Dim con As String
          con = .range("con").Value
          Dim cmd As String
          cmd = .range("cmd").Value

          With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:=con, Destination:=.Cells(10, 1))

              .CommandType = xlCmdSql
              .CommandText = cmd

              .FieldNames = True
              .RowNumbers = False
              .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
              .PreserveFormatting = True
              .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
              .BackgroundQuery = False
              .SaveData = True
              .AdjustColumnWidth = True
              .PreserveColumnInfo = True
              .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
              .RefreshPeriod = 0
              .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
              .MaintainConnection = False
          End With
      End With

  End Sub
  ```

  This code contains some properties you might not need, however, since this isn't much of a performance issue, we can always get rid of them later.

Works for me, let me know if you need any help.

[image]

Hope this helps.