# Transpose multiple columns to multiple rows in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have huge amount of data in an Excel spreadsheet that is currently in multiple rows. I'd like to transform this into multiple rows with three columns.

ID    Low     Med     high
1     10      20      30
2     11      22      33
3     22      32      21

Desired Outcome:
1   Low    10
1   Med    20
1   High   30
2   Low    11
2   Med    22
2   High   33
3   Low    22
3   Med    32
3   High   21

I would really appreciate your help. Thank You in advance!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?? There are plenty of question of this type (even just on SO) so you should easily find a basis to work with

Comment: another new post with the same topic and 2 answers on how to achieve what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846542/vba-convert-rows-to-columns